# Printing multiple lines of a dictionary

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I define type

```
type person = { last_name: string; first_name: string; age: int};;
let person1 = {last_name="Doe"; first_name="John"; age=30};;
```

How can I print

```
Last name : Doe
First name : John
Age : 30
```

I thought using

```
match person1  with
| {last_name=ln; first_name=fn; age=a} -> print_string ...;;
```

but it seems not the way to go. If `person1` and `person` were defined to be a dictionary with 1000 elements, then that solution doesn't hold.

Is there a better way to challenge that problem? Be aware that I have to use the functional paradigm. So I can't use `while` or `for` loop directly

Comment: How could `person1` be a dictionary with 1000 elements when it's of type `person`, which is a record with three elements? Are you just asking for a way to conveniently print anything for debugging?

Comment: @glennsl I know, but suppose the type `person` is also a dictionary of 1000 elements. In my main code, I have 25 elements, so using match/with seems not that great. I just want to iterate through that dictionary and print each element in a custom way ... similar as you can see in the question

Comment: @glennsl You seem to have some good experiences with ocaml. Do you have a solution to my question? Be aware that I have to use the functional paradigm. So I can't use `while` or `for` loop directly

Comment: You can access record fields directly, e.g., `person1.last_name`. No need to use pattern matching.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "iterate through that dictionary and print each element in a custom way". How do you expect to distinguish each field, and the type of type of each field, when you iterate through them in order to do the custom printing?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer your question because you seem to have two different ideas of your type simultaneously. You can't have a type that's both a record and a dictionary. It's not possible.

Generally speaking, a dictionary is a collection of things. The convention for collections in OCaml is that they have a function named `iter` that traverses the collection.

Imagine you have an abstract collection defined by a module `C`. Conventionally you'll have a type `'a C.t` for each collection, where `'a` is the type of the elements of the collection. You'll also have (conventionally) a function `C.iter` of this type:

```
C.iter : ('a -> unit) -> 'a C.t -> unit
```

This means you can pass a function (like your printing function) to `C.iter`, and then also pass a collection. The `iter` function will traverse the collection and call your function for every element.

In your case the module `C` would define the dictionary you're imagining, and the type `person C.t` would be the type of a dictionary of the records you show above. The function `C.iter` would have the type `(person -> unit) -> person C.t -> unit`. In other words, it would take a function and apply it to all the persons in the dictionary, one after the other.

We can't really say more unless we know the details of the dictionary that you are planning to create.

Comment: I was referring to a record. I thought the record was the same thing as a dictionary (similar in Python programming)

Comment: A record is not the same as a dictionary in any language (IMHO). A record consists of a small number of named values. A dictionary consists of an open-ended collection of arbitrary values each accessed by a key. There is some overlap in languages whose records are implemented with arbitrary field names. But field names in OCaml are fixed ahead of time. So there's no overlap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119842/print-certain-lines-only-if-it-is-not-an-empty-string-or-if-the-key-is-not-defin I think that question is for you. Only if you have a bit of time

Comment: I have modified my question. I have a beginning of an answer, but I don't know how to move on. It's been awhile I work on that, but I can't finish it. Can you give me a bit of help please? Look at the above link to see the update